# Getting NameError when using Cursors to read vertex coordinates in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, nameerror

I am new to python and having trouble Looping each feature in the new polygon shapefile, then use geometry cursors to read vertex coordinates of this lake polygon, identify the city that is the closest to the lake’s vertex, and add the city information into the fields of this lake feature.

```
for lake in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(In_Lakes,["OID@","SHAPE@"]):
    for feature in lake[1]:
        for vertex in feature:
        print vertex, vertex
Near_analysis(lake, In_Cities)
```

The error I get is:

> NameError: name 'Near_analysis' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is unrelated to your looping/iteration.

To see this try running this code snippet instead:

```
import arcpy
lake = "your_lake_layer_or_feature_class"
In_Cities = "your_In_Cities_layer_or_feature_class"
Near_analysis(lake, In_Cities)
```

and I would expect you to get the same error message.

You are receiving that error because there is not a function named `Near_analysis()` available to your script.

However, because you have presumably used `import arcpy` earlier in your script, there is a function named `arcpy.Near_analysis()` that you could use instead.

This will not give the same error (but your code may still need more work):

```
import arcpy
lake = "your_lake_layer_or_feature_class"
In_Cities = "your_In_Cities_layer_or_feature_class"
arcpy.Near_analysis(lake, In_Cities)
```

Comment: +1 This is a more efficient approach than integrating the feature geometry into near via a `for` loop.